# Can't docker container Next.js, golang, postgreSQL Error: no such host

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

Help me.

docker-compose files -> https://github.com/kametsun/Next-on-docker

I did this command "docker compose up api --build"

Docker version 24.0.7

Error:

```
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container pgsql_db  Running                                                                 0.0s 
 ✔ Container api       Created                                                                 0.0s 
Attaching to api
api  | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.
api  | 
api  | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
api  |  - using env:    export GIN_MODE=release
api  |  - using code:   gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
api  | 
api  | &{{0x40004950a0 false 0x109d70 0x40002be9f0 0x40002bec30}}
api  | 2023/12/25 07:21:46 failed creating schema resources: querying server version dial tcp: lookup db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
api  | exit status 1
api exited with code 1
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "next-app/ent"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    for {
        client, err := ent.Open("postgres", "host=db port=53 user=postgres dbname=db password=password sslmode=disable")
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println(client.User)
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }

    client, err := ent.Open("postgres", "host=db port=53 user=postgres dbname=db password=password sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {

        log.Fatalf("failed opening connection to postgres: %v", err)

    }

    if err := client.Schema.Create(context.Background()); err != nil {

        log.Fatalf("failed creating schema resources: %v", err)

    }

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "Hello, World!",
        })
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Please tell me what to do.

I try "docker compose up api --build"

I want connect PostgreSQL and create tables.

Comment: The database port is `5432` not `53`

Comment: It looks like `db` might not be the right host name.  Can you [edit] the question to include your `docker-compose.yml` file?  The right name will depend on what's defined there.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `db` as the hostname for your database in your connection string, but according to your docker-compose file, the service name of the database is `pgsql`. As Roman points out, you also need to use port 5432 rather than 53. But the 'no such host' error message is caused by the wrong host name.

So instead of

```
client, err := ent.Open("postgres", "host=db port=53 user=postgres dbname=db password=password sslmode=disable")
```

you need to use

```
client, err := ent.Open("postgres", "host=pgsql port=5432 user=postgres dbname=db password=password sslmode=disable")
```